# Hibernate @Embedded vs ManyToOne Mapping

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to create hibernate mapping between two tables `User` and `Country` as shown below in below image.

The `Country` table is used only for the user and not anywhere else so should i use embedded and Embeddable to create these tables or simply perform many to one mapping once tables get created.

[image]

Comment: @Dherik , thanks for editing my question. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you'll use it. If you embed the country data it will be in User table and will be loaded with user data.

If in most cases you don't need the country data each time you work with user data you can do OneToMany mapping with lazy initialization. In that case country data will be loaded only when need with the cost of additional DB hit (which may be reduced to a join).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when you want to load country data.If you use embedded then the country data will be loaded at the time of user data load.But if you go with OneToMany mapping with lazy initialization then country data will be loaded when you need it.
So that is based on you use.

Answer (score 0):

This is something more personal. Some people prefer to use Embedded to abstract some information and other people are more purist.

By my experience, I prefer to map the entities very close to their representation on tables. The reasons are simple:

- **Maintenance**: it's easier to understand what't happening on the mapping if some new developer enter on the team and he don't have many experience with hibernate.
- **Queries more similar to SQL**: your JPQL/Criteria queries will be more closest to the generated SQL. The abstraction of a embedded can bring some confusion, even for people familiar with the framework.

And as the other answers already mentioned, you will always bring the `Country` information with `User` using embedded. This is a **EAGER** behavior, what is generally something to avoid on JPA/Hibernate.

So, in your case, I would use a many-to-one relationship.